# Is it possible to do an Insert Into stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Basically I have a table of data and I would like to take the values of each row and feed it to the stored procedure.

In my perfect world, I'd do this

```
insert into StoredProcA @var1 @var2
select testdesc, testoption
from tableA
where testoption = 1
```

Well, I don't think that's going to work. So how, if possible, can I take the all data from a table/query and pass it to the stored procedure?

**EDIT**: The stored procedure already exists and does quite a bit of processing to the incoming data. The amount of data from the source table itself is only 300 rows.

Comment: Use can use a table valued parameter:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx.

Comment: And in the real world it will give you a syntax error :)

Comment: Why not put the SELECT in a while loop and execute the sproc each time.... how big is the query?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do a couple of things to get this going, since your parameter is getting multiple values you need to create a Table Type and make your store procedure accept a parameter of that type.

Since you are passing a `TABLE` as a parameter you will need to create a TABLE TYPE something as follows

**TABLE TYPE**

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.Prco_Table AS TABLE 
 (
    [Val1]         Data Type
    [Val2]         Data Type
  )
 GO
```

**Stored Procedure to Accept That Type Param**

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE mainValues 
 @TableParam Prco_Table READONLY   --<-- Accepts a parameter of that type 
 AS                                  -- Note it is ReadOnly 
 BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
  /* do your insert from this parameter or other cool stuff  */

  INSERT INTO Target_Table (Col1, Col2)
  SELECT [Val1] , [Val2]
  FROM  @TableParam    --<-- Table Type variable


END
```

**EXECUTE PROC**

Declare a variable of that type and populate it with your values.

```
 DECLARE @Table ClaimData(      --<-- Declare a variable of your type
          [Val1]         Data Type
          [Val2]         Data Type
                         ); 

 -- Populate the variable
   INSERT INTO @Table ([Val1],[Val2])
   SELECT testdesc, testoption
   FROM tableA
   WHERE testoption = 1

  EXECUTE mainValues  @Table --<-- Pass this variable of Table Type
```

Comment: please see EDIT above.

Comment: @dotnetN00b I have seen your edit you can alter your existing procedure add a table table parameter and insert the values inside the proc where ever you want to insert it. there is no other way around unless you want select values inside your procedure and insert them inside your procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using @logixologist suggestion and used a cursor.

It worked quite well.

```
declare testCursor cursor
for
select testdesc, testoption
from tableA
where testoption = 1

open testCursor
declare @p1 varchar(max), @p2 varchar(8)

fetch next from testCursor into @p1, @p2
while (@@fetch_status <> -1)
begin
   if (@fetch_status <> -2)
   exec db1.dbo.usr_storedproc @p1, @p2
   fetch next from testCursor into @p1, @p2
end
close testCursor
deallocate testCursor
go
```

If anyone has any improvements, better way, or different way of doing this, please post solution as an answer.

Comment: I'd suggest you consider rewriting your SP to @M.Ali solution; Cursors in Sql are pretty slow and sooner or later their performance will bite you...