# How to use declared table values to delete from a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm passing a delimited string to a stored procedure that enters the values into the declared table when it runs into the delimiter,

Here is my Stored Procedure.

```
 Alter PROCEDURE s_BulkDeleteTest
(
@IDString VarChar(200)
)
AS
-- Creating Variables
DECLARE @numberLength int
DECLARE @numberCount int
DECLARE @TheIDs VarChar(200)
DECLARE @sTemp VarChar(100) -- to hold single characters

-- Creating a temp table
DECLARE @T TABLE 
(
 TheIDs VarChar(500)
)
--Initializing Variables for counting 
SET @numberLength = LEN (@IDString)
SET @numberCount = 1
SET @TheIDs = ''

--Start looping through the keyword ids
WHILE (@numberCount <= @numberLength)

BEGIN
SET @sTemp = SUBSTRING (@IDString, @numberCount, 1)
    IF (@sTemp = ',')
        BEGIN
            INSERT @T(TheIDs) VALUES (@TheIDs)
            SET @TheIDs = ''
        END
    IF (@sTemp <> ',')
        BEGIN
            SET @TheIDs = @TheIDs + @sTemp
        END
        SET @numberCount = @numberCount + 1
END
```

This all works fine for adding the values to the @T table, but then I added this..

```
delete from [Subjects]
where (select TheIDs from @T) = SubjectID
```

that threw an error about there being more than one value in the declared table @T.
So I was wondering how can I use the values in @T and delete all those ID's from my Subjects table.

Comment: This is a very poorly designed procedure. You should consider using a Table Valued Parameter here.

Comment: @M.Ali - please tell me why this is a bad proc. thank you. chenqui.

Comment: All this complicated and performance killer while loop and string manipulations can be easily avoided by using ONE table values parameter. Try your self and see the difference. Create a procedure with TVP and create one same as shown in this question and see the difference your self.

Comment: @M.Ali, This may look like a poorly designed procedure and it should because I'm not a SQL Developer.

Comment: It was only a suggestion, you can learn more about it since you are working with sql server :). Have a look at this question if you are interest in learning more about [`Passing A table as Parameter to a Stored Procedure`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887500/is-it-possible-to-do-an-insert-into-stored-procedure)

Comment: @M.Ali, thanks for the link, I will definitely check it out :). the reason for this procedure is because, the user clicks a button and it pulls values from a table and puts it in a dataset, from there I dynamically create the buttons with the values that I need, so they can click on multiple buttons and those ID's are put into a string and then I pass the string to the procedure to delete every single record by way of the ID. With my explanation does my procedure still seem poorly designed?

Comment: I would declare a table variable of that TVP type and populate that table each time user clicks, Once clicking is done pass the table to this procedure. Your procedure in this current state will run into problems if a user has clicked quite a few time and the concatenated string exceeds 200 characters. as you have a variable which can only accommodate 200 characters. Not knowing much about application but would you like to control how many time a user can click so the number of values doesnt exceed 200 characters or just let the users click as many times as they want and just make your code to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `in`:

```
delete from [Subjects]
    where SubjectId in (select TheIDs from @T);
```

A result set with multiple rows cannot be equal to a single value.

EDIT:

The expression `(select TheIds from @T)` returns a set of values.  The `=` operator works on scalar values, not sets.  So, it doesn't normally work with this construct. The `in` operator compares a scalar to a set. so it does work.

There is one exception.  When the subquery returns one row and one column, then it is converted to a scalar value.  So, the expression would work if there were one row returned, or if you forced one row, as in:

```
    where SubjectId = (select top 1 TheIDs from @T);
```

Of course, `in` would work in this situation as well.

Comment: Thank you sir, I will accept this once I am able to. Could you explain why the "in" made this work?

Comment: please refer to google for the IN clause in SQL server.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev, just did "The IN operator allows you to specify multiple values in a WHERE clause."

Comment: I see, thank you for taking the time to explain it for me. Its appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If `TheIDs` has any null values using IN operator will delete unexpect rows. I would suggest using EXISTS operator something like this...

```
DELETE FROM [Subjects] 
WHERE EXISTS 
             (SELECT 1
              FROM @T
              WHERE [Subjects].SubjectId = TheIDs)
```